# question about showing integral is zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a real valued function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ we have that $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f$ is measurable. If $\mu(\{x\in X\;|\; f(x)\in B\})=\mu(\{x\in X\;|\; -f(x)\in B\})$  and this is true for all Borel sets $B$, then show integral  $\int_X f d\mu=0$ when the integral exists.